# Assigning false returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

the following code is outputting "undefined" but when x is true, it works.
If I assign string 'false' it is correct.

Does anyone have an idea?

```
var _obj= {"istrue":false};
var y = (x)=>({z:x.istrue})
const uCall = y(_obj);
console.log(uCall.z);
```

### Update

I updated the code to reflect my actual code.

When I run the code in browser it works but when I run it in a service, it returns undefined.

Comment: `y` is a function. It has no `z` property.

Comment: y is a function (and an object), y.z is the z property of function y ... the function itself is never called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading the `z` property of the function instance. You need to call your `y` function, with a parameter.

```js
var x= false;
var y = (x)=>({z:x})
console.log(y('testing123').z);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you aim to achieve. You are setting the variable y as a function which takes x as an argument (not the global variable x but an argument x). If you run y(x) then you'll receive an object {z: false}